# Unity VideoPlayer cannot play iPhones videos on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I am encountering an issue on Unity 2022.3.21f where I cannot seem to stream videos recorded by an iPhone on Android.

To isolate this problem, I create an empty Unity Project and add a VideoPlayer to the scene targeting my video URL. It works fine on iOS and macOS, but on Android, I get the following message:

```
AndroidVideoMedia: Could not create decoder for mime type video/dolby-vision.
```

I am testing on a Google Pixel 7 Pro running Android 14.

The common point of these videos seems to be the "BT.2020 HLG" color profile.
Converting a video having this profile to something like "HD" works.

It also seem that using ExoPlayer via AVProVideo works (not using MediaPlayer though).
However I cannot find strong confirmation that this video format is not supported by Android nor Unity.
Using AVProVideo is not an option for me due to its price and I am seeking confirmation that what I am trying to achieve with Unity is not a bug or a missing setting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From AOSP project site: https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/hdr#dolby-vision-decoder-support so `SoC vendors and OEMs must do additional work to enable HDR platform support for a device.`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I did not consider this information enough, thinking an high-end Google phone would implement HDR. I also based my though on the fact that I could open the videos with my Gallery, but maybe ExoPlayer is used here too.

Comment: To my understanding 'HDR' is a bit of a catch-all for various codecs/profiles so all I can suggest is looking at the [Android Compatibility Definition Document](https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/14/android-14-cdd#538_dolby_vision) which is only 'required'  for the original OS released with device and checking [ExoPlayer's issues on github](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues?q=is%3Aissue+dolby-vision) Found [this one](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/8530) but don't know the details of what unity plugin you are using.

Comment: Thank you I better understand that I should not expect every Android phone to be compatible with this format. I am using no specific Unity plugin, I wanted to make it work on the provided VideoPlayer component, which as I understand it does not use ExoPlayer.